# Current cell height inside the heightForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table with static cells. For one cell I want to change its height depending on the label's height (inside that cell) and at the same time leave all other cells height intact. How can I get current cell's height? Or maybe there is better approach?

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([indexPath section] == 2) {
        return self.myLabel.frame.origin.y *2 + self.myLabel.frame.size.height;
    } else {
        return ...; // what should go here, so the cell doesn't change its height?
    }
}
```

Comment: Your cell's default height goes there. 44 if you didn't change anything.

Comment: You can also calculate the cell's actual needed height for the label by using UIKIt's extension to NSString method `sizeWithFont:`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can call:

```
[super tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
```

in the else block so you don't have to worry if ever you changed the default height.

Answer (score 4):

You can get/set default height `tableView.rowHeight`, or you can store your height before changing cell height, so you can get default height from some variable;

Answer (score 1):

Please do this one

```
if ([indexPath section] == 2)
{
    if(indexPath.row == 1)
         return self.myLabel.frame.origin.y *2 + self.myLabel.frame.size.height; 
    else 
         tableView.rowHeight
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@talnicolas great answer, here's for Swift 3:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.section == 2 {
        let easy = self.myLabel.frame
        return easy.origin.y *2 + easy.size.height
    } else {
        return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAt: indexPath)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You, maybe, want to calculate height of label in constrained width. In this case you can create method like that:

```
- (CGFloat)textHeightOfMyLabelText {
    CGFloat textHeight = [self.myLabel.text sizeWithFont:self.myLabel.font constrainedToSize:LABEL_MAX_SIZE lineBreakMode:self.myLabel.lineBreakMode].height;
    return textHeight;
}
```

and use result in `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`. 
Don't forget to add margin value of you label.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == youSectionNumber)
    {
        if (indexPath.row == numberOfrow)
        {
            return self.myLabel.frame.origin.y *2 + self.myLabel.frame.size.height;
        }
    }

      return 44; // it is default height of cell;
}
```